# Could slow router cause Request timeout when pinging?

Tags: timeout, ping, router, lan

Environment:

```
1 router

Multiple LAN servers
192.168.1.1 (HTTP server)
192.168.1.2 (FTP server)
192.168.1.3 (MYSQL server)
...

Multiple wireless devices

Total connected devices more than 50.
```

When pinging to 192.168.1.1(not specific), here is what I get

```
...
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5295 ttl=64 time=3.809 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5296 ttl=64 time=3.279 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5297 ttl=64 time=4.147 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5298 ttl=64 time=3.571 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5299
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5300
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5301
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5302
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5303
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5304
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5305
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5306
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5307
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5308
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5309
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5310
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5311
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5312
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5313
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5314
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5315
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5316
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5317
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5318
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5319
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5320
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5321
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5322
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5323
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5324
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5325
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5326
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5327
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5328 ttl=64 time=7.284 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5329 ttl=64 time=7.094 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5330 ttl=64 time=4.889 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5331 ttl=64 time=4.877 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5332 ttl=64 time=4.030 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5333 ttl=64 time=8.854 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=5334 ttl=64 time=4.671 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5335
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5336
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5337
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5338
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5339
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5340
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5341
...
```

The problem is not specific for 192.168.1.1. I have tried other hosts e.g. ftp server, mysql server. Same problem occurs. I get ***intermediate*** Request timeout.

**However said**, 192.168.1.1 (HTTP server) get most Request timeout (38.8% packet loss), compared to 192.168.1.2 (FTP server) only 2.7% packet loss.

I suspecting the speed of the router is causing the problem where it lost some packets. How can I verify it is the problem of the router but not others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no request timeout problems on other hosts, the reason for causing time-out does not seems to related to the router.

Try review the target host network configuration such as ***iptable*** and compare the file with other running hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using some other device or router if you have one ?

Comment: I am planning to replace the router. Which router would you suggest? I need something more than household uses.

Comment: Linksys WRT54GL Wi-Fi Wireless-G Broadband Router try this